# Do Colomares Castle's tickets run out?

Tags: public-transport, europe, spain, malaga, andalusia

I am planning to visit Malaga around 3rd October. I want to visit the Colomares Castle that day but I want it to be more of a spontaneous trip. Means I don't want to make any advance bookings for the local transport or the castle?

Would it be okay if I just bought them the same day? For both the buses from Malaga + the castle? Or is it a risk to wait till too long.